# How to change color to text of ActionBar's menu items?

Tags: android, menuitem, android-theme, android-menu

I want to change the color of the text of menu items in the action bar. I' tried to change the theme but nothing works. I'm ussing API 19:

This is my `res\values\styles.xml`

```
<resources>
    <!--
        Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
        by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!--
            Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
            res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
            backward-compatibility can go here.
        -->
    </style>

    <!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
        <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="LoginFormContainer">
        <item name="android:padding">28dp</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Also the project generated styles.xml in `res\values-v11\` `res\values-v14\`

I don't know if I have to change the theme or just set a property or something, any help I will really appreciate. Thank you!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/23392083/603270

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a solution to my problem. This is my final code:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!--
        Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
        AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
        res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
    -->
    <style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
        <item name="android:textAppearanceLargePopupMenu" >@style/m_textAppearanceLargePopupMenu</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu" >@style/m_textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu</item>
    </style>

    <style name="m_textAppearanceLargePopupMenu" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Large">
        <item name="android:textColor">#009ad2</item>
    </style>
    <style name="m_textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.PopupMenu.Small">
        <item name="android:textColor">#009ad2</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

It is my `res\values-v14\` file code.

I was confused, what I really wanted was to  **change the text color to the PopupMenu** and it worked for me.

Thanks friends for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomText) in the section **Customize the Text Color**. It says the way you have to do it for the different android API levels.

Comment: Saludos desde Sonsonate.